# Gerund vs. a+verb

Tags: grammar, nouns, gerunds, present-participles

When you describe the action, which ones are used, and what does the other pair's usage and meaning (a + verb), if they are unfit?

> - 1. This is a walk.
>   2. This is walking.
> - 3. This is a buy.
>   4. This is buying.
> - 5. This is a sleep.
>   6. This is sleeping.

Comment: "Walk" in number 1 is a noun, not a verb. So is "buy" in number 2. "Sleep" in number 3 is an uncountable noun, so it can't take "a" as the article. Please learn what a gerund is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is walking.
>   This is buying.
>   This is sleeping.

There are few contexts I can think of where using these sentences would be appropriate. The two that I can think of are:

- Something said as part of a demonstration or example. Perhaps you are explaining a word to a non-English speaker. You walk, and tell them that "this is (called) *walking*."
- Something said to emphasize that "this" is a particularly good example of "-ing." A common example of the phrase being, "(now) this is living," which means that the speaker considers their current lifestyle to be a good one, and probably one they wouldn't change.

---

> This is a walk.
>   This is a buy.
>   This is a sleep.

As @P.E.Dant said, these are all nouns (not verbs), and #3 is incorrect. Generally, *sleep* is an uncountable noun, although it can be countable in certain contexts. For example:

> There are two sleeps until Christmas.
>   ***Meaning:*** There are two nights left until Christmas day.

I can only imagine *this is a walk* being said in the context of a [sponsored walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkathon), when somebody asks what you are doing: "*This is a walk (to raise money for charity).*"

*This is a buy* is slightly more applicable. It's quite common to describe a low price for a product as *a good buy*. The term is also used for drug deals, as in "*it's a (drug) buy*".

---

I'm not certain that I've completely understood your question, but I will try to answer it.

If you are trying to describe what you are currently doing, you would say:

> I am walking.
>   I am sleeping.

This can also be used to describe future actions:

> I am buying a house (next Tuesday).

Be careful when using *buying*, as in certain contexts you may want to use *shopping* instead. Compare their definitions (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**buy**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/buy)
>   [WITH OBJECT]
>   Obtain in exchange for payment:
>   "*she bought six first-class stamps*"
>   "*he had been able to buy up hundreds of acres*"
>
> [WITH TWO OBJECTS]: "*he bought me a new frock*"
>   [NO OBJECT]: "*homeowners who buy into housing developments*"
>
> ---
>
> [**shop**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shop)
>   [NO OBJECT]
>   Visit one or more shops or websites to buy goods:
>   "*she shopped for groceries twice a week*"
>   "*sometimes it's more convenient to shop online*"
>
> [WITH OBJECT]: "*take a trip to downtown San Diego to shop the upscale stores of Horton Plaza*"